# Rails template - adding index to :created_at using generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I'm creating a Rails template.  The template includes `generate(:model, "Post", "content:string", "user_id:integer:index")`, which works fine to generate a model for Post.  However, I'd also like to add an index to the timestamp `:created_at` using the `generate` command for Rails templates.  Is this possible within the previously mentioned generate model, or via another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can simply pass additional arguments to generate, example: `"created_at:datetime:index"` and `"--no-timestamps"`

```
$ rails g model post content:string user_id:integer:index updated_at:datetime created_at:datetime:index --no-timestamps

   invoke  active_record
   create    db/migrate/20140712155207_create_posts.rb
   create    app/models/post.rb
   invoke    test_unit
   create      test/models/post_test.rb
   create      test/fixtures/posts.yml 

$ cat db/migrate/20140712155207_create_posts.rb

 class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :posts do |t|
       t.string :content
       t.integer :user_id
       t.datetime :updated_at
       t.datetime :created_at
     end
     add_index :posts, :user_id
     add_index :posts, :created_at
   end
 end
```

Alternatively, you could always generate a migration after the model generation:

```
$ rails generate migration AddIndexToPosts created_at:datetime:index
```

Obviously, you would need to make this conform the `generate()` syntax.